# YOLOv3 resolution and execution time per image inference

Tags: object-detection, opencv, yolo, python

I would like to get more insight into why the execution time per inference changes when the image size changes. Here is what I think I know and why I'm confused:

The standard YOLOv3 implementations are provided in 3 different resolutions (Yolov3-320, YOLOv3-416, YOLOv3-608). This means the Yolo architecture may accept any image size but internally it is up or downscaled to the target resolution so there aren't any shape issues.

For me that means when looking at execution time it doesn't make much difference whether I provide an input image of size 1024x1024 or 800x800 when using for example the YOLOv3-416 architecture.

But when I do image inference it actually does make a huge difference whether I choose the lower resolution image over the higher resolution image. And also the quality of the detections changes slightly too. With the same image downscaled before the model the detections are sometimes not as good.

For inference I use the opencv integration with:

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(model_cfg, model_weights)
net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU)

IMG_WIDTH=frame.shape[1]
IMG_HEIGHT=frame.shape[0]
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1 / float(255), (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),[0, 0, 0], 1, crop=False)

net.setInput(blob)
outs = net.forward(get_outputs_names(net))
```

But I measure the inference time only for the forward pass through the network. But maybe it gives you more insight into why the inference time changes when I scale the image before the inference.

Comment: image rescaling is computed by `cv2.dnn.blobFromImage`. Is it also included in your computation time ? Could you give an idea of what you mean by "huge difference" please ?

Comment: As I said I only measure the inference time for net.forward(). With huge difference I mean from about 0.5s for 416x416 to 1.6s for 832x832 But again in the YOLO architecture there should be a resizer layer (for YOLOv3-416 the bigger dimension will be resized to 416) so the network should see both images as the same, right?

Comment: I don't really care about the inference time, but this kind of differences in execution time would indicate that the YOLO net actually works with the higher resolution image. Which would explain the slightly better detection accuracy with a higher resolution

Comment: I think in the case you have `IMG_WIDTH=IMG_HEIGHT=416`. As I said, the resize is computed by `cv2.dnn.blobFromImage` thus at the input of the network itself, the `blob` has the same size in both cases. I need to test on my side...

Comment: Oh I see thats a misunderstanding, I set IMG_WIDTH=frame.shape[1] and IMG_HEIGHT=frame.shape[0]. I will clarify that in the question

Comment: I tried to analyse the network though with getLayersShape(). I haven't found the right way to format it so I know which shape is for which layer. But it seems like the shapes are dependent of the input shape. Like there doesn't seem to be a reshape layer that reshapes to 416x416 quite the opposite there seem to be some pooling layers that half the image resolution by a factor of two. This for me means that the YOLO architecture is indeed able to change for different image shapes (like a fully convolutional network), or the dnn module is able to change the architecture to fit the blob size

Comment: Indeed YOLO is fully convolutional thus in theory it can manage images of any size. It would explain the difference in processing time according to input image size. But I though that in practice the `blob` had to have a fixed size.

Comment: Well that explains it but why then have different YOLO implementations? Yes I keep the blob size constant over the network existence.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to analyse the network with getLayersShape(). I haven't found the right way to format it so right now I don't know which shape is for which layer. But it seems like the shapes are dependent of the input shape. Like there doesn't seem to be a reshape layer that reshapes to 416x416, quite the opposite there seem to be some pooling layers that half the image resolution by a factor of two. This for me means that the YOLO architecture is indeed able to work with different image shapes (like a fully convolutional network), or the dnn module is able to change the architecture to fit the blob size